# Event-based Xbox Controller polling

Tags: java, library, wrapper

The goal of the following code is to be able to use an Xbox Controller in a Java program, it works with the [jinput](https://github.com/jinput/jinput) library.

Unfortunately this library is rather old, has little to no documentation and uses a polling system. There are some existing event-based (xbox) controller input systems, but most of them are embedded in 3D game engines, so I got the idea to make my own library, these are the ultimate goals:

- It should support multiple types of controllers.
- It should have some kind of plug-in system for the native DLLs, so instead of jinput I should be able to use some other library.

These goals have not been met yet, as currently it just wraps over the jinput library.

In order to understand some of the weird stuff that is going on in my classes, you will need to understand the following things that are going on in the jinput library:

- The left and right triggers are represented as a single z-axis, so you are not able to identify if the left or right trigger is held down, you instead get an average value of both triggers. If you hold down the left trigger only, you get a value of 1, if you hold down the right trigger only you get a value of -1 and if you hold down both triggers or neither, then you get a value of 0.
- It uses 0f and 1f to represent not pressed and pressed button states.
- For the D-pad (directional pad) it uses the values 0f, 0.125f, 0.25f, 0.375f, 0.5f, 0.625f, 0.75f, 0.875f and 1f for respectively the off state and the possible buttons that have been pressed down.
- The event system provided by jinput is non-blocking, meaning that still need to loop every time interval and read all events that have occured since last time.
- I haven't been able to get the rumblers of the controller to work, so there is no support for this at all in my library.

Some relevant information about jinput can be found [in this topic](http://www.java-gaming.org/index.php?topic=16866.0) rather than in non-existing documentation.

With that said, I have implemented the following:

- An event-based system where you can attach listeners to all events.
- A Xbox Controller-implementation where the names of every component correspond to logical names rather than some generic names that are very hard to work with.
- An option to set deadzone for sticks and triggers, more information about deadzones can be found [in this excellent post](http://www.third-helix.com/2013/04/12/doing-thumbstick-dead-zones-right.html).

Usage of my library:

```
XboxGamepad xboxGamepad = new XboxGamepad(controller, 10);

xboxGamepad.setDeadzone(XboxGamepad.Component.LEFT_STICK_X_AXIS, XboxGamepad.DeadzoneType.RADIAL, 0.5f);
xboxGamepad.setDeadzone(XboxGamepad.Component.LEFT_STICK_Y_AXIS, XboxGamepad.DeadzoneType.RADIAL, 0.5f);

xboxGamepad.setDeadzone(XboxGamepad.Component.RIGHT_STICK_X_AXIS, XboxGamepad.DeadzoneType.RADIAL, 0.25f);
xboxGamepad.setDeadzone(XboxGamepad.Component.RIGHT_STICK_Y_AXIS, XboxGamepad.DeadzoneType.RADIAL, 0.25f);

xboxGamepad.setDeadzone(XboxGamepad.Component.TRIGGER_AXIS, XboxGamepad.DeadzoneType.LINEAR, 0.1f);

xboxGamepad.addListener(XboxGamepad.Component.RIGHT_STICK_BUTTON, ButtonPressedEvent.class, event -> System.out.println("Pressed right stick button @ " + event.getTime()));
xboxGamepad.addListener(XboxGamepad.Component.RIGHT_STICK_BUTTON, ButtonReleasedEvent.class, event -> System.out.println("Released right stick button @ " + event.getTime()));
xboxGamepad.addListener(XboxGamepad.Component.RIGHT_STICK_BUTTON, ButtonClickedEvent.class, event -> System.out.println("Clicked right stick button @ " + event.getTime() + " for " + (event.getClickTime() / 1_000_000) + "ms"));
xboxGamepad.startListening();
```

where `controller` is obtained via the jinput API, more specifically:

```
List<Controller> gamepads = Arrays.stream(ControllerEnvironment.getDefaultEnvironment().getControllers())
        .filter(controller -> controller.getType().equals(Controller.Type.GAMEPAD))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
Controller controller = gamepads.get(0);
```

Following the library classes will be listed.

**XboxGamepad.class**

```
/**
 * @author Frank van Heeswijk
 */
public class XboxGamepad {
    private static final List<List<Component>> RADIAL_DEADZONE_AXES = Arrays.asList(
        Arrays.asList(LEFT_STICK_X_AXIS, LEFT_STICK_Y_AXIS),
        Arrays.asList(RIGHT_STICK_X_AXIS, RIGHT_STICK_Y_AXIS)
    );

    private final Controller gamepad;
    private final int pollDelay;

    private final EventQueue eventQueue;
    private final net.java.games.input.Event event;

    private final Map<Component, Map<Class, List<Consumer<Event>>>> componentEventListeners = new EnumMap<>(Component.class);

    private final Map<Component, Long> buttonLastPressedTime = new EnumMap<>(Component.class);

    private final List<Deadzone> axisDeadzones = new ArrayList<>();
    private final Map<Component, List<Deadzone>> axisToDeadzonesMap = new EnumMap<>(Component.class);

    private final Map<Component, Float> axisValues = new EnumMap<>(Component.class);
    private final Map<Component, Boolean> axisInDeadzone = new EnumMap<>(Component.class);

    private Timer pollTimer;

    public XboxGamepad(Controller gamepad, int pollDelay) {
        this.gamepad = gamepad;
        this.pollDelay = pollDelay;

        this.eventQueue = gamepad.getEventQueue();
        this.event = new net.java.games.input.Event();
    }

    public void startListening() {
        if (pollTimer != null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You are already listening to events");
        }
        pollTimer = new Timer(true);
        this.pollTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                poll();
            }
        }, 0, pollDelay);
    }

    public void stopListening() {
        if (pollTimer == null) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("You never started listening to events");
        }
        pollTimer.cancel();
        pollTimer = null;
    }

    public <T extends Event> void addListener(Component component, Class<T> eventClass, Consumer<T> eventListener) {
        Objects.requireNonNull(component, "component");
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventClass, "eventClass");
        Objects.requireNonNull(eventListener, "eventListener");
        componentEventListeners.putIfAbsent(component, new HashMap<>());
        Map<Class, List<Consumer<Event>>> eventListenerMap = componentEventListeners.get(component);
        eventListenerMap.putIfAbsent(eventClass, new ArrayList<>());
        List<Consumer<Event>> eventListeners = eventListenerMap.get(eventClass);
        eventListeners.add((Consumer<Event>)eventListener);
    }

    public void setDeadzone(Component component, DeadzoneType deadzoneType, float value) {
        if (value < 0f) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("You cannot set a deadzone with a negative value: component = " + component + ", deadzoneType = " + deadzoneType + ", value = " + value);
        }
        switch (deadzoneType) {
            case LINEAR:
                addDeadzone(new Deadzone(component, Arrays.asList(component), deadzoneType, value));
                break;
            case RADIAL:
                List<Component> radialAxes = RADIAL_DEADZONE_AXES.stream()
                        .filter(axes -> axes.contains(component))
                        .findFirst()
                        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Component " + component + " is not part of a radial deadzone axes group"));
                addDeadzone(new Deadzone(component, radialAxes, deadzoneType, value));
                break;
        }
    }

    private void addDeadzone(Deadzone deadzone) {
        axisDeadzones.add(deadzone);
        axisToDeadzonesMap.clear();
        for (Deadzone axisDeadzone : axisDeadzones) {
            for (Component axis : axisDeadzone.axes) {
                axisToDeadzonesMap.putIfAbsent(axis, new ArrayList<>());
                axisToDeadzonesMap.get(axis).add(axisDeadzone);
            }
        }
    }

    private void poll() {
        gamepad.poll();
        while (eventQueue.getNextEvent(event)) {
            net.java.games.input.Component component = event.getComponent();
            float value = event.getValue();
            long timeNanos = event.getNanos();
            if (!component.isAnalog()) {
                if (component.getIdentifier() == net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Axis.POV) {
                    //directional pad
                    if (value == 0f) {
                        fireEvent(DPAD_ANY, new ButtonReleasedEvent(timeNanos));
                    }
                    else {
                        Component dpadComponent = dpadToComponent(value);
                        if (dpadComponent == null) {
                            System.out.println("Unable to process dpad value " + value);
                        }
                        else {
                            fireEvent(dpadComponent, new ButtonPressedEvent(timeNanos));
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    //button
                    Component buttonComponent = buttonToComponent(component.getIdentifier());
                    if (buttonComponent == null) {
                        System.out.println("Unable to map button " + buttonComponent);
                    }
                    else {
                        if (value == 1f) {
                            buttonLastPressedTime.put(buttonComponent, timeNanos);
                            fireEvent(buttonComponent, new ButtonPressedEvent(timeNanos));
                        } else if (value == 0f) {
                            fireEvent(buttonComponent, new ButtonReleasedEvent(timeNanos));
                            fireEvent(buttonComponent, new ButtonClickedEvent(timeNanos, timeNanos - buttonLastPressedTime.getOrDefault(buttonComponent, timeNanos)));
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.println("Unable to process button value " + value + " for " + buttonComponent);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else {
                //no button
                Component axisComponent = axisToComponent(component.getIdentifier());
                if (axisComponent == null) {
                    System.out.println("Unable to map axis " + axisComponent);
                }
                else {
                    axisValues.put(axisComponent, value);
                    List<Deadzone> activeDeadzones = axisToDeadzonesMap.getOrDefault(axisComponent, Collections.emptyList());

                    if (activeDeadzones.isEmpty()) {
                        //no deadzone
                        fireEvent(axisComponent, new AxisMovedEvent(timeNanos, value));
                    }
                    else {
                        //has at least one deadzone associated
                        for (Deadzone deadzone : activeDeadzones) {
                            if (deadzone.deadzoneType == DeadzoneType.LINEAR) {
                                float absoluteValue = Math.abs(value);

                                if (absoluteValue < deadzone.value) {
                                    if (!axisInDeadzone.getOrDefault(axisComponent, false)) {
                                        fireEvent(axisComponent, new AxisMovedEvent(timeNanos, 0f));
                                        axisInDeadzone.put(axisComponent, true);
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }

                                float newValue = value * ((absoluteValue - deadzone.value) / (1f - deadzone.value));
                                if (axisComponent == deadzone.eventAxis) {
                                    fireEvent(axisComponent, new AxisMovedEvent(timeNanos, newValue));
                                    axisInDeadzone.put(axisComponent, false);
                                }
                            }
                            else if (deadzone.deadzoneType == DeadzoneType.RADIAL) {
                                Component deadzoneXAxis = deadzone.axes.get(0);
                                Component deadzoneYAxis = deadzone.axes.get(1);

                                float xValue = axisValues.getOrDefault(deadzoneXAxis, 0f);
                                float yValue = axisValues.getOrDefault(deadzoneYAxis, 0f);

                                float magnitude = (float)Math.sqrt(Math.pow(xValue, 2) + Math.pow(yValue, 2));
                                if (magnitude < deadzone.value) {
                                    if (!axisInDeadzone.getOrDefault(axisComponent, false)) {
                                        fireEvent(axisComponent, new AxisMovedEvent(timeNanos, 0f));
                                        axisInDeadzone.put(axisComponent, true);
                                    }
                                    continue;
                                }

                                if (deadzoneXAxis == axisComponent && axisComponent == deadzone.eventAxis) {
                                    float newXValue = (xValue / magnitude) * ((magnitude - deadzone.value) / (1f - deadzone.value));
                                    fireEvent(axisComponent, new AxisMovedEvent(timeNanos, newXValue));
                                    axisInDeadzone.put(axisComponent, false);
                                }
                                else if (deadzoneYAxis == axisComponent && axisComponent == deadzone.eventAxis) {
                                    float newYValue = (yValue / magnitude) * ((magnitude - deadzone.value) / (1f - deadzone.value));
                                    fireEvent(axisComponent, new AxisMovedEvent(timeNanos, newYValue));
                                    axisInDeadzone.put(axisComponent, false);
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                System.out.println("Unknown deadzone type " + deadzone.deadzoneType);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static Component dpadToComponent(float value) {
        if (value == 0.125f) {
            return DPAD_UPLEFT;
        }
        else if (value == 0.25f) {
            return DPAD_UP;
        }
        else if (value == 0.375f) {
            return DPAD_UPRIGHT;
        }
        else if (value == 0.5f) {
            return DPAD_RIGHT;
        }
        else if (value == 0.625f) {
            return DPAD_DOWNRIGHT;
        }
        else if (value == 0.75f) {
            return DPAD_DOWN;
        }
        else if (value == 0.875f) {
            return DPAD_DOWNLEFT;
        }
        else if (value == 1f) {
            return DPAD_LEFT;
        }
        else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private static final Map<net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier, Component> BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    static {
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._4, LEFT_SHOULDER_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._5, RIGHT_SHOULDER_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._8, LEFT_STICK_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._9, RIGHT_STICK_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._0, A_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._2, X_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._3, Y_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._1, B_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._6, BACK_BUTTON);
        BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Button._7, SELECT_BUTTON);
    }

    private static Component buttonToComponent(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier button) {
        return BUTTON_COMPONENT_MAP.get(button);
    }

    private static final Map<net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier, Component> AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP = new IdentityHashMap<>();
    static {
        AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Axis.X, LEFT_STICK_X_AXIS);
        AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Axis.Y, LEFT_STICK_Y_AXIS);
        AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Axis.RX, RIGHT_STICK_X_AXIS);
        AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Axis.RY, RIGHT_STICK_Y_AXIS);
        AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP.put(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier.Axis.Z, TRIGGER_AXIS);
    }

    private static Component axisToComponent(net.java.games.input.Component.Identifier axis) {
        return AXIS_COMPONENT_MAP.get(axis);
    }

    private void fireEvent(Component component, Event event) {
        componentEventListeners.getOrDefault(component, Collections.emptyMap()).getOrDefault(event.getClass(), Collections.emptyList()).forEach(listener -> listener.accept(event));
    }

    public static enum Component {
        LEFT_SHOULDER_BUTTON,
        RIGHT_SHOULDER_BUTTON,
        LEFT_STICK_BUTTON,
        RIGHT_STICK_BUTTON,
        A_BUTTON,
        X_BUTTON,
        Y_BUTTON,
        B_BUTTON,
        BACK_BUTTON,
        SELECT_BUTTON,
        DPAD_ANY,
        DPAD_UP,
        DPAD_UPRIGHT,
        DPAD_RIGHT,
        DPAD_DOWNRIGHT,
        DPAD_DOWN,
        DPAD_DOWNLEFT,
        DPAD_LEFT,
        DPAD_UPLEFT,
        LEFT_STICK_X_AXIS,
        LEFT_STICK_Y_AXIS,
        RIGHT_STICK_X_AXIS,
        RIGHT_STICK_Y_AXIS,
        TRIGGER_AXIS
    }

    private static class Deadzone {
        private Component eventAxis;
        private final List<Component> axes;
        private final DeadzoneType deadzoneType;
        private final float value;

        private Deadzone(Component eventAxis, List<Component> axes, DeadzoneType deadzoneType, float value) {
            this.eventAxis = eventAxis;
            this.axes = axes;
            this.deadzoneType = deadzoneType;
            this.value = value;
        }
    }

    public static enum DeadzoneType {
        LINEAR,
        RADIAL
    }
}
```

**Event.class**

```
public interface Event {
    long getTime();
}
```

**ButtonEvent.class**

```
public interface ButtonEvent extends Event {
}
```

**ButtonPressedEvent.class**

```
public class ButtonPressedEvent implements ButtonEvent {
    private final long time;

    public ButtonPressedEvent(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ButtonPressedEvent(" + time + ")";
    }
}
```

**ButtonReleasedEvent.class**

```
public class ButtonReleasedEvent implements ButtonEvent {
    private final long time;

    public ButtonReleasedEvent(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ButtonReleasedEvent(" + time + ")";
    }
}
```

**ButtonClickedEvent.class**

```
public class ButtonClickedEvent implements ButtonEvent {
    private final long time;
    private final long clickTime;

    public ButtonClickedEvent(long time, long clickTime) {
        this.time = time;
        this.clickTime = clickTime;
    }

    public long getClickTime() {
        return clickTime;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ButtonClickedEvent(" + time + ", " + clickTime + ")";
    }
}
```

**AxisEvent.class**

```
public interface AxisEvent extends Event {
}
```

**AxisMovedEvent.class**

```
public class AxisMovedEvent implements AxisEvent {
    private final long time;
    private final float newValue;

    public AxisMovedEvent(long time, float newValue) {
        this.time = time;
        this.newValue = newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public float getNewValue() {
        return newValue;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "AxisMovedEvent(" + time + ", " + newValue + ")";
    }
}
```

I'd like to have my code reviewed on all aspects. I already identified some possible issues:

- Maybe Component should be split into AxisComponent and ButtonComponent?
- There are some pretty long methods in the XboxGamepad class.
- There is no general abstraction for a controller as some of these things, like deadzones, triggers and buttons are likely to be shared over other controller types.

Ultimately I plan to release this as a separate GitHub repository and provide it as a Maven library.

Answer (score 4):

A few thoughts, based on general concerns

`startListening` and `stopListening` suggest lifecycle management, which in turn suggests that there is a state machine here.  The fact that you are throwing `IllegalStateException` is supporting evidence.  But your state machine implementation is currently implicit.  You should make it explicit.

In particular

- Can `startListening` be called again after `stopListening` has been invoked?
- Does it make sense to call `addListener` or `setDeadzone` after `startListening` has been invoked?

I don't know what the right answer is for the controller library; but the library should be written in such a way that the answers are obvious to the users.

It seems to me that the XboxGamepad you have implemented has too many different responsibilities.

- In your example, where you are invoking `addListener` and `setDeadzone`, it looks like a `Builder`
- In `startListening` and `stopListening`, it looks like a `LifeCycleManager`
- In `startListening`, it appears to be a `Factory`
- In `poll`, it's an `EventListener`

For instance, I made an attempt at refactoring the `startListening` method.

```
public void startListening() {
    if (pollTimer != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You are already listening to events");
    }
    pollTimer = new Timer(true);
    this.pollTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            poll();
        }
    }, 0, pollDelay);
}
```

So the first thing I see is that XboxGamepad doesn't need a `pollDelay` itself; it is just passing it through to somebody else.  For instance, suppose we had a little `PollingScheduleFactory`, implemented so:

```
class PollingScheduleFactory {
    private final int pollDelay;

    public Timer schedule(final Runnable task) {
        Timer pollTimer = new Timer(true);
        pollTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                task.run();
            }
        }, 0, pollDelay);

        return pollTimer;
    }
}
```

Then startListening would look like

```
public void startListening() {
    if (pollTimer != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You are already listening to events");
    }
    pollTimer = this.pollingScheduleFactory.schedule(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                poll();
            }      
    });
}
```

Which didn't buy me as much as I had hoped.  What I think the code should look like is

```
public void startListening() {
    if (pollTimer != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You are already listening to events");
    }
    pollTimer = this.pollingScheduleFactory.schedule(pollTask);
}
```

if you can re-use the same task after the next stop/start, or

```
public void startListening() {
    if (pollTimer != null) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("You are already listening to events");
    }
    pollTimer = this.pollingScheduleFactory.schedule(pollTaskFactory.newTask());
}
```

if you need a new instance every time around.  The code looks cleaner, but it doesn't eliminate the need to create an inner class instance somewhere.

But if can separate the polling from the LifeCycle management, then we get a much nicer line.  From your example, I'm imagining something like

```
XboxGamepad.Builder builder = new XboxGamepad.Builder(controller, 10);
builder.setDeadzone(...);
builder.addListener(...);
XboxGamepad gamepad = builder.build();

gamepad.startListening();
```

Where Builder.build() looks something like....

```
public XboxGamepad build () {
    PollTask pollTask = new PollTask(gamepad, eventListeners, ...);
    PollingScheduleFactory scheduleFactory = new PollScheduledFactory(pollDelay);
    ...
    return new XboxGamepad(pollTask, scheduleFactory);
}
```

Again, if the pollTask can be different after each start, then a pollTaskFactory would be passed in instead.

If I were implementing this library, I'd want to go the extra mile to use a [Fluent Builder](http://blog.crisp.se/2013/10/09/perlundholm/another-builder-pattern-for-java).  And I would also consider `setLinearDeadzone` and `setRadialDeadzone` -- a Fluent Builder, or a *family* of Fluent Builders, can take a lot of the burden off of your clients without necessarily removing the flexibility offered by the generic interface.

```
public interface Event {
    long getTime();
}
```

If all of your events are going to be handling time the same way, then you should probably be implementing an `AbstractEvent` that manages that for you.

```
abstract class AbstractEvent implements Event {
    private final long time;

    protected AbstractEvent(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    long getTime() {
        return this.time;
    }
}
```

The Deadzone code looks very suspicious

```
private static class Deadzone {
    private Component eventAxis;
    private final List<Component> axes;
    private final DeadzoneType deadzoneType;
    private final float value;

    private Deadzone(Component eventAxis, List<Component> axes, DeadzoneType deadzoneType, float value) {
        this.eventAxis = eventAxis;
        this.axes = axes;
        this.deadzoneType = deadzoneType;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

So the Deadzone itself is just a bag of data, with no behavior of its own...

```
for (Deadzone deadzone : activeDeadzones) {
    if (deadzone.deadzoneType == DeadzoneType.LINEAR) {
        // many words
    } else if (deadzone.deadzoneType == DeadzoneType.RADIAL) {
        // more many words
    }
}
```

but the DeadzoneType is used to switch behaviors of some other object?  That's usually a Wrong Thing.  I would at least expect the DeadzoneType to be used to look up a `Strategy`, from an EnumMap perhaps, if the Deadzone class itself can't do the Right Thing on its own.